# Legend placement in Python multiple plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am creating python subplots. I have 10 figures and I want to place legend out side of my plot. After trying alot I have came up with this code. However, It is placing the legend in middle, which is not looking nice.

```
 thres = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

 lav_tom= [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
 lav_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
 lav_hd =[63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31] 
 ax1 =plt.subplot(5,2,1)             # the first subplot in the first figure
ax1.plot( thres, lav_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax1.plot( thres, lav_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax1.plot( thres, lav_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax1.set_ylim(0,100)
ax1.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax1.set_title("LAV")
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('small')
**plt.legend(  loc= 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (0.54,0.02), ncol=3)**

lmv_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lmv_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lmv_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax2 =plt.subplot(5,2,2)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax2.plot( thres, lmv_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax2.plot( thres, lmv_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax2.plot( thres, lmv_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax2.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.set_title("LMV")


lmxv_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lmxv_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lmxv_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax3 =plt.subplot(5,2,3)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax3.plot( thres, lmxv_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax3.plot( thres, lmxv_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax3.plot( thres, lmxv_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax3.set_ylim(0,100)
ax3.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax3.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax3.title.set_text("LMXV")



lst_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lst_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lst_hd = [65.78,72.24,72.94,72.36,70.83,68.24,64.04,56.07,39.9]
ax4 =plt.subplot(5,2,4)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax4.plot( thres, lst_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax4.plot( thres, lst_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax4.plot( thres, lst_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax4.set_ylim(0,100)
ax4.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax4.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax4.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax4.set_title("LST")


lbaj_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lbaj_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lbaj_hd = [62.52,69,71.72,71.13,67.96,62.56,54.28,42.67,27.54]
ax5 =plt.subplot(5,2,5)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax5.plot( thres, lbaj_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax5.plot( thres, lbaj_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax5.plot( thres, lbaj_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax5.set_ylim(0,100)
ax5.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax5.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax5.set_title("LBAJ")


lbar_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lbar_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lbar_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax6 =plt.subplot(5,2,6)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax6.plot( thres, lbar_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax6.plot( thres, lbar_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax6.plot( thres, lbar_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax6.set_ylim(0,100)
ax6.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax6.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax6.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax6.set_title("LBAR")


lbas_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lbas_cloud = [81.12, 85.94, 87.2, 87.8,87.86, 85.77,82.72, 78.02,61.68]
lbas_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax7 =plt.subplot(5,2,7)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax7.plot( thres, lbas_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax7.plot( thres, lbas_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax7.plot( thres, lbas_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax7.set_ylim(0,100)
ax7.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax7.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax7.set_title("LBAS")




lboj_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lboj_cloud = [88.66, 88.68, 88.6, 88.55,88.53, 88.43,88.41, 88.34, 88.26]
lboj_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax8 =plt.subplot(5,2,8)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax8.plot( thres, lboj_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax8.plot( thres, lboj_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax8.plot( thres, lboj_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax8.set_ylim(0,100)
ax8.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax8.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax8.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax8.set_title("LBOJ")


lbor_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lbor_cloud = [89.42,89.4,89.35,89.41,89.4,89.35,89.33,89.28,89.27]
lbor_hd = [63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax9 =plt.subplot(5,2,9)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax9.plot( thres, lbor_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax9.plot( thres, lbor_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax9.plot( thres, lbor_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax9.set_ylim(0,100)
ax9.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax9.set_title("LBOR")


lbos_tom = [69.89, 76.92, 77.79, 78.6, 77.17, 72.67, 67.29, 58.73, 38.01]
lbos_cloud = [83.29, 83.1, 83.04, 82.98, 82.84, 82.75, 82.62, 82.52, 82.31]
lbos_hd =[63.18, 70.07, 71.18, 71.33, 68.9, 63.56, 58.05, 46.51, 26.31]
ax10 =plt.subplot(5,2,10)             # the second subplot in the first figure
ax10.plot( thres, lbos_tom, 'ks--', label = "TC")
ax10.plot( thres, lbos_cloud, 'ko--', label ="CS")
ax10.plot( thres, lbos_hd, 'k*-', label ="HD")    
ax10.set_ylim(0,100)
ax10.set_xlim(0.1, 0.9)
ax10.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax10.set_title("LBOS")

#plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Can anyone please suggest some better placement?

Comment: Look at the examples in http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location ; note that the subplots are declared leaving room for the external legend.

Comment: I would simply go for `plt.legend(loc='lower left',  ncol=3)` although you did not want the legend inside the plot. Another thing, i would plot the series in the order 'CS', 'TD' and then 'HD', in that case the order in the legend has the same order as the lines from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!!